# Pandas Groupby Divide by Last in Sequence by Unique Key

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: toy = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['7/1/2018','7/2/2018','7/3/2018','7/4/2018','7/2/2018','7/3/2018','7/4/2018','7/5/2018'],
                    'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'B':[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],'C':[4,7,2,6,4,2,2,1],
                    'key':['key1','key1','key1','key1','key2','key2','key2','key2']})

In [3]: toy
Out[3]:
   A  B  C      Date   key
0  1  8  4  7/1/2018  key1
1  2  7  7  7/2/2018  key1
2  3  6  2  7/3/2018  key1
3  4  5  6  7/4/2018  key1
4  5  4  4  7/2/2018  key2
5  6  3  2  7/3/2018  key2
6  7  2  2  7/4/2018  key2
7  8  1  1  7/5/2018  key2

In [4]: toy.groupby('key')['A'].last()
Out[4]:
key
key1    4
key2    8
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

For each unique key, I want to return the value in column A for the most recent date. So for key1 the most recent day is 7/4/2018 and the value in column A is 4 and for key2 the most recent day is 7/5/2018 and the value in column A is 8.

Then I want to divide all the data in columns B & C (and in reality many more columns) by 4 if key1 and 8 if key2. For my actual data I have thousands of keys and 100 or so columns I would like to divide by the key-last-column A value. The date ranges are independent for each key.

I know that, assuming the DataFrame is sorted ascending by date, I can get the denominator by using:

```
toy.groupby('key')['A'].last()
```

But I can't figure out how to divide the values in each column B & C for each key by this value.

Hopefully I've formulated to problem clearly, happy to clarify as necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`transform('last')`** instead of **`last`**, then simply divide:

```
df[['B', 'C']].div(df.groupby('key').A.transform('last'), axis=0)

       B      C
0  2.000  1.000
1  1.750  1.750
2  1.500  0.500
3  1.250  1.500
4  0.500  0.500
5  0.375  0.250
6  0.250  0.250
7  0.125  0.125
```

To show *why* this works:

```
df.groupby('key').A.transform('last')

0    4
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    8
5    8
6    8
7    8
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

By using **`transform('last')`** instead of **`last`**, every element in the series is "transformed" to the last value in each group.  Then we can simply divide each row by the equivalent value in this result.

Comment: Good catch with transform :)

Comment: Wow thanks! That was fast and did it. To be honest I'm not exactly sure why it works though

Comment: @whamp I added an explanation, if you need to me to clarify anything please ask!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but this should help.

```
toy_gby = toy.groupby('key')

keys_values = toy_gby['A'].last()

keys_df = pd.DataFrame(keys_values)

keys_df = keys_df.reset_index()

keys_df = keys_df.rename(columns = {'A':'new_column'})

merged_df = pd.merge(toy,keys_df, on =['key'])

merged_df['B'] = merged_df['B']/merged_df['new_column']
merged_df['C'] = merged_df['C']/merged_df['new_column']
```

I am trying to create a new column which has the value to divide the other columns you wanted to divide.